# Gradle Dependency for BigQuery JDBC Driver

Tags: google-bigquery

I can download a zip file for BigQuery JDBC driver from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers#how_do_i_get_support_for_these_drivers but I want a maven or Gradle dependency for this driver.

Is this driver available a a gradle/maven dependency?